# Integrate Kaplan-Meier estimator quickly in R

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier

I am searching for R code for computing the following integral

$\int\limits_t^{a}(x-t){\widehat S\left( x \right)dx}$, where $t$ and $b$ are fixed constants and $\widehat S\left( x \right)$ is the Kaplan-Meier estimator for a survival function defined by $\widehat S\left( t \right) = \prod\limits_{{X_j} \le t} {\left( {1 - \frac{{{d_j}}}{{{n_j}}}} \right)}$.

Is there a faster way to compute this integral for a survival data, (2,3+,2,9,16,18+,7,17,5,5+): +symbol denotes the censored observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "survival" library, you can compute the estimated survival curve with the function

`ff = survfit(Surv(x, ind)~1)`

Then by accessing the survival values and times in the ff object through \$surv and \$time, respectively, you can use these values in the function

`approxfun`

which can then be integrated numerically using the function

`integrate`

Comment: @J McVittie Yes..!! Works perfectly. Many thanks. :)

Comment: Consider upvoting answers that help you, as well as accepting them